# How can I make a 3D scan shell into a solid object?

Tags: modeling

I've tried everything. I have a 3D scan that is essentially just a shell. It has complex geometry, which makes it difficult.

I've tried the solidify modifier with a large thickness, but I have to clamp the surface so that the shape remains. In the end, it still doesn't thicken the shell by much. I want a solid object from the shell.

Also, I tried making a large cube and using the boolean modifier to cut the shell away from the inside of the cube. I was hoping it would create two objects: the object that I want, and the excess part of the cube on the outside. I used another program to cut the cube to see inside and I can see the outline but I can't split the two.

So, is there an easy way to make a shell solid? Or is there a way that I can split the two objects?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a screenshot or a .blend?

Comment: Yeah I can try. Another problem is that it's a very large file. Should I try to upload the .blend of the imported STL file?

Comment: If a screenshot is not enough, upload the blend.